# Android Pay errorCode = 8 when generating MaskedWalletRequest

Tags: android-pay

I'm building a `MaskedWalletRequest`:

```
return MaskedWalletRequest.newBuilder()

    // required fields
    .setCurrencyCode(CURRENCY_CODE)
    .setEstimatedTotalPrice(String.valueOf(order.getTotal()))

    // optional fields
    .setShippingAddressRequired(false)
    .setMerchantName(MERCHANT_NAME)
    .setPhoneNumberRequired(false)
    .setPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters(tokenizationParameters)
    .setMerchantTransactionId(String.valueOf(order.getId()))
    .addAllowedCardNetwork(123)
    .build();
```

I then start SupportWalletFragment:

```
SupportWalletFragment supportWalletFragment 
    SupportWalletFragment.newInstance(walletFragmentOptions);

MaskedWalletRequest maskedWalletRequest = createMaskedWalletRequest();

WalletFragmentInitParams initParams = 
    createWalletFragmentInitParams(maskedWalletRequest);

supportWalletFragment.initialize(initParams);
```

When I click on generated Android Pay button, my `onActivityResult` gets correct request code, result code = 1, and data Intent has error value of 8.

I don't see this error code in the `WalletConstants` class ([link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants) ). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the "8" may be coming from the [CommonStatusCodes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#constants) class.

It turns out the allowed card network was invalid. I just dropped '123' in there for a quick test. I can only pass in one of these [network ints](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants.CardNetwork). I was hoping for a much more clear error string like the other errors generated during the Android Pay process.

Answer (score 0):

When you tap “Buy with Android Pay “ button more than once - errorCode 8 occurs.

With respect to the above Masked Wallet builder please refer to the documentation on allowedCardNetworks() for more information.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/MaskedWalletRequest.Builder#addAllowedCardNetwork(int)